# How to force upperdir overlayfs to reread/reload lowerdir?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm having the following problem with an overlayfs: I can mount an overlayfs fine using the following line in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
none /home/student overlayfs lowerdir=/home/student,upperdir=/home/.student_rw 0 0
```

This works great and the `mount` command displays the overlayfs correctly:

```
pc:~$ mount -l -t overlayfs
none on /home/student type overlayfs (rw,lowerdir=/home/student,upperdir=/home/.student_rw)
```

So now when a student logs out of the machine I delete the contents of `/home/.student_rw` using a script – which also works fine.

The problem is that the student logging in should find a clean home directory with the settings preconfigured in `/home/student` as the overlayfs does not touch the lowerdir folder. However overlayfs "remembers" the deleted files and does not show them, even if they exist in the lowerdir. After a reboot this approach works fine. I want that to work on logout and login though. How can I fix this problem? For me a possible solution seems to be to let the upperdir reread the lowerdir. How would I do that?

The exact same approach worked very well for aufs, which are no longer supported in precise.

Comment: Have you found any solution badgerhill? thx

Answer (score 5):

Simply execute:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

This will make the kernel drop caches, dentries and i-node data from memory.